# Node.js Error: ENONET

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express framework,

```
//Handlebars Middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

My directory looks like:

[image]

and it gives the below error whenever I try to run.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
open 'C:\Users\Sourav\forum\bin\views\layouts\main.handlebars'
```

Any help is appreciated. It's my first question so, every suggestion regarding question clarity is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: From what I can tell, your views dir, isn't in bin/ - So the error message is correct.  You should use __dirname, '../views'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Looks to me like bin and views are on the same level, so it doesn't make sense to look in `.../bin/views/...`, I would use dirname if possible.

Comment: It is more helpful if you include the linked information in your question.

Comment: Problem solved. thanks @LokiSinclair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__dirname in this case is pointing inside bin folder, instead of './views' use '../views'